# Random Forest Selective Node splitting

Tags: split, random-forest

I am working on a random forest model, wanted to know if there is any possible method/hack/workaround to split a selective node bypassing the parameters passed.
For eg: I have set the `min_samples_leaf` parameter to `4` and I have a specific node which I want to split further (maybe 2 samples only for those 2 leaves).

I can't set the `min_samples_leaf` to a lower parameter for the whole tree because the data is small and will lead to overfitting.